# c# How to Create a jagged array using data from multiple files

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to create a jagged array that i can sort and do stuff with. 
I have 7 text files containing 1022 lines of data each. The Array i need is an array of 1022 arrays containing 7 elements each (basically 1 line from each file per array)

I've never used a jagged array before and while i can find lots online about how they are made i can't seem to find anything about how to populate them that helps me do this. I can make the array and make it the size i want but populating it is where i'm lost.

Really appreciate any help you can give me with this.

Comment: LINQ is probably your easiest path. You'll not have to populate it manually if you use LINQ.

Comment: I've never had any experience with LINQ, Could you explain how i'd use this to do what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the `File.ReadLines` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get an enumerable sequence of all the lines in a file:

```
var source = new []
{
    File.ReadLines(@"C:\dir\file1.txt"),
    File.ReadLines(@"C:\dir\file2.txt"),
    File.ReadLines(@"C:\dir\file3.txt"),
    File.ReadLines(@"C:\dir\file4.txt"),
    File.ReadLines(@"C:\dir\file5.txt"),
    File.ReadLines(@"C:\dir\file6.txt"),
    File.ReadLines(@"C:\dir\file7.txt"),
};
```

You then need to pivot the seven sequences of 1022 lines each into 1022 sequences of seven items each:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> Pivot<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        return PivotIterator(source);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T[]> PivotIterator<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
    {
        var enumerators = new List<IEnumerator<T>>();
        try
        {
            foreach (IEnumerable<T> item in source)
            {
                enumerators.Add(item.GetEnumerator());
            }

            bool stillGoing = true;
            while (stillGoing)
            {
                foreach (IEnumerator<T> item in enumerators)
                {
                    if (!item.MoveNext())
                    {
                        stillGoing = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (stillGoing)
                {
                    var result = new T[enumerators.Count];
                    for (int index = 0; index < enumerators.Count; index++)
                    {
                        result[index] = enumerators[index].Current;
                    }

                    yield return result;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (IDisposable item in enumerators)
            {
                item.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call [the `Enumerable.ToArray` extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get a jagged array:

```
string[][] result = source.Pivot().ToArray();
```

Comment: That does exactly what i needed. Thanks

Comment: If there an easy way to convert this to output an int[][] array instead of string?

Comment: @iMxAndyy: Assuming every line of the file is a valid integer, you could change the items in the `source` array to: `File.ReadLines(@"C:\dir\file1.txt").Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)).Select(int.Parse)`. Obviously, if any line from any of the files can't be converted to an integer, then you'll get an exception.